# Postgres Count without groupby (using jpa)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have been using mariaDB, and now I am moving to postgres.
i have a query in JPA

```
select count(<primarykeycolumn>) from tablename where condition
```

But Postgres gives an error saying a `group by` clause is needed.

I don't want to add a group by, the code is up and running with mariaDB.

Below is the error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "app_movie_summary.creationdate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 55
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable ORDER BY CREATIONDATE DESC
Query: ReportQuery(name="App_Movie_Summary.findAllByCreationDateCount" referenceClass=App_Movie_Summary sql="SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM mytable ORDER BY CREATIONDATE DESC")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2677)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that MariaDB executes invalid SQL. What is the query **supposed** to do? Why don't you want to fix it?

Comment: Yes you *do* want a `group by` - even in MariaDB - if you want a "correct" answer and not just random values. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you cannot mix aggregate functions (like `count`) with unaggregated columns (`creationdates`) unless you `GROUP BY` the unaggregated columns. In this case, it doesn't look like you need to group after all because you have no need to `ORDER BY creationdate`. Order is irrelevant to `count(*)`. This query is perfectly valid:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable
```

If you do want `creationdate` included, you *must* `GROUP BY` it. When you do that, `ORDER BY` also makes sense again:

```
SELECT creationdate, count(*) from mytable
GROUP BY creationdate
ORDER BY creationdate
```